# What does the concept of an "infinite universe" actually mean?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, terminology, universe, definition

When physicists talk about the universe being infinite, or wondering whether it is or not, what do these two options actually mean? I am not interested whether the universe is infinite or not, I am interested in what are the two options actually looking like.

Does an "infinite universe" mean infinite space, but when you go far enough there isn't any matter anymore, just more of infinite empty space in that direction?
Or does an "infinite universe" mean infinite matter, where it doesn't matter how far you go, you will find infinite stars all along the way?

In short, is the "infiniteness" meant to apply to space or to matter (which then would also include space of course)?

Comment: Continuing my personal understanding in a comment, since it's not really part of the question: The idea of a finite universe always seemed silly to me, since I can't image how the "border" of the universe would look like; surely you can always go further. So I'm inclined to believe the concept of an "infinite universe" means infinite matter, but I was never sure.

Comment: we don't know.${}$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I am asking for the meaning of a common concept in physics, not for the state of reality. Surely when physicists talk about the concept, they know what they mean? The meaning is the only thing I am looking to learn.

Comment: @Nohus It is possible to have a finite universe that is borderless. In a simple case, if you “keep going forward” you could eventually just come back to where you started. This kind of space would be a “3-sphere”.

Comment: @G.Smith There are other topologies than a 3-sphere with this property, e.g. a 3-torus.

Comment: I might be wrong about this, but I thought the only shape that fits GR that gives a finite universe was a 3 sphere. Totally possible I missed something though.

Comment: @OscarSmith You’re thinking of FLRW spacetimes, which are everywhere homogeneous and isotropic. If we relax these (very strong) constraints, we can put Einstein’s equations on essentially whatever topology we’d like.

Comment: This is a reply to your comment that finite universe "seemed silly". This is owing to an incomplete understanding of what space can do. The same logic, for example, might cause one to say that the Earth must have an infinite surface because the idea of the surface coming to stop somewhere seems silly. The logic is faulty because it does not take into account what is possible for the geometry and topology of a curved space.

Comment: @OscarSmith no there's a bit more to it. You can have local homogeneity and isotropy and a finite space for any sign of curvature, but the global isotropy does not hold for finite space of non-positive curvature. The 3-torus is an example of finite space of zero curvature and local but not global isotropy.

Comment: If space was infinite then it would have to be matter at the same density everywhere (i.e no area of empty space larger than the one we can see now) because that would imply that it had a center, which we are reasonably certain it doesn't have - based on Hubbles observations.

Answer (score 32):

Generally when physicists talk about the universe being finite, they are talking about the existence of an upper bound $R$ on the distance between any two points in space.  Such an upper bound could arise in several ways - perhaps the universe has an edge - a boundary which cannot be crossed - or perhaps the universe has the topology of a 3-sphere, and so if one travels sufficiently far in any direction they would eventually return to their starting point.  A spatially infinite universe is one which does not have this feature - given any real number $M$, there exist two points in the universe which are separated by a distance which is greater than $M$.

A finite universe of course can presumably only host a finite amount of matter.  An *infinite* universe could in principle host either a finite or infinite amount of matter.  Mainstream cosmology generally assumes the cosmological principle, which states that on sufficiently large scales the distribution of matter in the universe is homogeneous; in such cases, an infinite universe would have an infinite amount of matter in it, but of course this principle may not be accurate.

Comment: Thank you, so as I understand the answer, there are generally three possible states, but the "infinite space with finite matter" one is not considered likely.

Comment: @Nohus Right.  Observations indicate that the universe is, on very large scales, quite homogeneous; that being said, we are restricted to observations of the *visible* universe, and it's possible that on scales vastly larger than that, the matter distribution is not homogeneous at all.  In the absence of any evidence to the contrary, most physicists would probably guess that we do *not* occupy such a special position in the universe.  But who knows?

Comment: @Nohus: It's ([apparently](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612183/how-do-we-know-the-distance-between-stars-without-assuming-flat-spacetime)) also considered unlikely that our universe has the topology of a 3-sphere, because space appears to have no curvature at large scales.  However that doesn't preclude a finite unbounded universe with pacman topology _(no curvature, but opposite ends of the universe still wrap around)_

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I love that "pacman topology" is something that you can seriously mention in a physics discussion, and its likely the most accurate description of what you mean.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I don't think it's accurate to say that it's unlikely that the topology is closed; rather, the statement should be that if the universe is finite, the largest distance is much bigger than what we can measure.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Wouldn't "pacman topology" (a 3-torus, if I'm not mistaken) imply 3 "special" directions or axes for wraparound? It would strike me as strange and "un-elegant" for actual space to have special directions in this way...

Comment: There's something kind of wonderful about the idea that in cosmology circles, the "flat earth" concept has been writ-large to a flat-universe hypothesis...

Comment: How does an infinite homogeneous universe fit with the Big Bang idea? All matter which came from a single event would be inside a light-cone, which always has finite diameter in any frame of reference.

Comment: @aschepler That is a common misconception.  The big bang model does not say that all matter in the universe came from a single event. [The big bang happened *everywhere*](https://phys.org/news/2015-02-big.html).

Comment: @Qami Yes, such a model would lack global isotropy - a characteristic of multiply-connected models.  My personal preference, however, is to adopt a position of radical agnosticism about such things.  Nature is, after all, under no obligation to contort herself to fit our barely-evolved ideas about elegance :)

Comment: @J.Murray That article isn't exactly helpful for this. It's talking about a fallacy of trying to associate some position at the present time with the origin event, but that doesn't make sense whether the universe is finite or infinite. It uses the "dots on a balloon" thought experiment, which does imply a single (position, time) origin, a small universe diameter shortly after the time of the bang, and a finite diameter later, just without a boundary or "center".

Comment: @aschepler Alright, for a less pop-sci description see e.g. the cosmology chapter of any intro GR text. The idea is that there is no single point in space where the big bang occurred. Imagine a 3D coordinate grid with spacing $\delta$ which extends to infinity in every direction, with an inertial observer sitting at every grid point.  Now imagine taking $\delta\rightarrow 0$.  At every moment in time, the grid is infinitely large, but the spacing between observers is just getting smaller.  That's the big bang (in a spatially infinite universe) in reverse.

Comment: @J.Murray Makes sense. For the finite models on the other hand, do they usually suppose that the surfaces in spacetime within $dt$ of big-bang conditions have a diameter/volume approaching zero as $dt \rightarrow 0$, or approaching some positive "initial size"? Or could either work?

Comment: @aschepler In the FLRW spacetime with positive spatial curvature, the scale factor plays the role of the comoving radius of the 3-sphere, so as $t\rightarrow 0$ the volume of the space would go to zero.  I don't know if there are other big bang models which do not have this feature, though.

Comment: @Qami: Yes, it would imply special directions. I think most people think it's not true because of that inelegance, but we don't get to choose what universe we live in, and the laws of physics [aren't always elegant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yArprk0q9eE). _(Side note: Pacman topology would not be a 3-torus since that has intrinsic curvature)_

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Fair enough, regarding your point on elegance/inelegance! To your side note, though: can you elaborate a bit? I didn't think a 3-torus implied curvature...at least, the wikipedia article describes it as a cube with opposite pairs of sides "glued together", which matches my current understanding...

Comment: @Qami: Sorry, I should be more precise with my words. What I meant is that they're not isomorphic _(they result in different spacial geometry, so we'd actually notice a difference between the two)_. The wiki article is talking about "topological equivalence", aka homeomorphism, where eg. a sphere is equivalent to a cube, a torus is equivalent to a coffee mug, etc.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I think in this context one refers to the *flat torus*, that is, a Riemannian manifold homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$, but with constant curvature zero. Not a "usual" torus embedded in any higher dimensional space.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft actually, GR would not admit the Pacman topology without the space actually being curved.  We just think it's _so large_ that the curvature is not apparent even in the CMB.

Comment: @JDługosz Yes it can. A manifold with a toroidal topology can be intrinsically flat.

Comment: @user76284 so?  GR does not do that.  If it's not intrinsically curved, it won't loop back on itself.  You would need a mechanism outside of spacetime in order to wrap it into a loop like that.

Comment: @JDługosz That's not true.  For instance, the 2-torus (the surface of a donut) can be endowed with a flat connection whose Riemann tensor vanishes everywhere.  It's not the connection induced by embedding in 3D Euclidean space (which indeed is *not* flat), but that doesn't matter.  Whether a "straight" curve will ultimately loop back on itself is a global topological property which cannot be inferred from its (local) intrinsic curvature.

Comment: I think you are agreeing with me, in that it would take something outside of GR to make it connect that way.

Comment: @JDługosz No, I am disagreeing - it is entirely possible within the framework of GR to have a spacetime with the global topological structure $\mathbb R \times T^3$ and everywhere-vanishing Riemann curvature.  My understanding is that you're asserting that if spacetime has toroidal spatial topology, then it must possess non-vanishing intrinsic curvature, is that not accurate?

Comment: @Qami Side note about isotropy: [there seems to be a mathematical obstruction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056173/is-there-a-compact-flat-isotropic-manifold) to a negatively curved or flat compact and isotropic universe. This is very unsatisfying to me.

Comment: @JDługosz If you’re unfamiliar with the subject, that’s fine. Ask. But don’t go around making false “corrections” to people who know what they’re talking about. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe#Universe_with_zero_curvature) and [here](https://www.americanscientist.org/sites/americanscientist.org/files/200522415348_306.pdf), for example.

Comment: @user76284 If you don't understand the point I'm making, don't belittle me with accusations that I made some different statement instead.  The Wikipedia passage and the paper both simply point out that there are various internally flat topologies; they don't address what would cause space to _do_ that.  Let me counter with Sean Carroll's _Biggest Ideas in the Universe!_ lecture series.

Comment: @JDługosz I think I understand what you're saying.  GR is a local theory, and so the global topology of spacetime is something which we must impose by hand. You're saying that if spacetime is topologically non-trivial (multiply-connected, etc) then there must be some deeper explanation beyond the scope of GR which would explain that. That's reasonable, but I'd add that the same would be true of a trivial space. In other words, the idea that spacetime should "naturally" be like $\mathbb R^4$ rather than $\mathbb R\times T^3$ and that the latter topology requires explanation while [...]

Comment: [...] the former does not is a philosophical prejudice which doesn't really stand up to scrutiny.  There's a sense in which $\mathbb R^4$ would be *simpler*, but that's what the ancients thought about geocentrism too.

Comment: @JDługosz No, I perfectly understand what you’re saying. Your claim that “GR would not admit the Pacman topology without the space actually being curved” is *factually wrong*. Period.

Comment: @JDługosz You don’t need to “cause” the toroidal spacetime to “do” anything. It simply *is* that way. You seem to have some severe misunderstandings of GR.

Comment: @JDługosz “Let me counter with Sean Carroll's *Biggest Ideas in the Universe!* lecture series.” What about it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting how the amount of matter in an infinite universe could be "either... finite or infinite", without space being absolute.  My understanding is that "absolute space" went down the drain when GR was formulated.  ("Absolute" usually has a theosophical connotation, with reality germinating somewhere within the mind or uterus of a hypothetical Being, rather than a relativistic one.)

Comment: @Edouard I'm afraid I don't know what that means. An infinite universe which contains a single particle would be perfectly consistent with the framework of GR.

Comment: Wouldn't it be kind of difficult for a single pointlike particle to simultaneouslty occupy all 3 of the spatial dimensions, even aside from the fact that, as pointed out by Vilenkin in "The Principle of Mediocrity" (available free online), "simultaneity...is not well-defined in General Relativity"?  Space is never absolute, as its curvature can vary with its occupancy by mass.

Comment: @Edouard I don't know what it means to "occupy all three of the spatial dimensions."  In any arbitrary reference frame, that single particle would be localized to one point in space at any given time.  I'm not sure what simultaneity has to do with this, either.  It appears you may have some misconceptions as to how GR works; I would suggest asking a dedicated question of your own if you want a longer and more satisfying answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not wanting to ask a question:  I'm trying to differentiate your answer from the others.  What Vilenkin saw as an imprecise definition of "time and simultaneity" in GR had a bearing on the possibility that your single particle might occupy different points in space at different times, which you've allowed.  (I appreciate that clarification.)  The pointlike nature of any subatomic particle, though it's conventional in 1915's GR, may have been seen by Einstein as problematic, since he endorsed 1929's Einstein-Cartan Theory, which provides a tiny spatial extent for fermions.

Comment: @Edouard Einstein-Cartan is a classical theory, so it doesn't have anything to do with fermions.  In any case, the nature of the matter in the universe (pointlike or otherwise) is irrelevant to my main point, which is that there's nothing about GR which forbids a universe which has a single, localized cluster of matter surrounded by a vacuum of infinite spatial extent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122693/discussion-between-edouard-and-j-murray).

Answer (score 10):

When cosmologists talk about an infinite Friedmann universe, they mean one with infinite spatial volume, finite and uniform matter density (averaged over cosmological scales), and thus infinite matter. There would be galaxies as far as you care to go, even if you could go far beyond what we call the “cosmological horizon”.

Comment: That answers the "infinite" side, thank you. But seeing that the question is unresolved (correct me if I'm wrong), what would it mean for the universe to be finite? Would it mean the space is finite, or matter is finite in infinite space, or are both options considered (and thus the terminology is unclear)?

Comment: @Nohus That warrants a separate question. In this question you asked what an infinite universe means.

Comment: @Nohus But I will answer it anyway in a comment: A finite Friedmann universe has finite spatial volume, finite and uniform matter density, and thus finite matter.

Comment: In my first sentence I asked "what do these two options actually mean?", which I thought takes precedence on how I titled my actual question in the post. But thank you for answering in the comment!

Comment: The word “finite” does not even appear in your question.

Comment: I interpreted the “two options” as the two options for an infinite universe which you mentioned in your second and third paragraphs.

Comment: My bad, I should have worded it better, and I can see how you could read it that way without reading my mind. I will leave it as is to not generate more confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is best to mention the three major possibilities of "universal shapes" that exist today.

Let me start by saying that cosmologists envision the universe as a four-dimensional spacetime continuum that can exist in a variety of shapes as long as the shape conforms to the field equations of Einstein's general theory of relativity.

Hornet-shaped spacetime.
And let me start with a very strangely shaped universe. The funnel formed spacetime. Look [here](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn4879-big-bang-glow-hints-at-funnel-shaped-universe/) or [here](https://www.islamicity.org/2333/now-they-say-it-is-shaped-like-a-trumpet/). This is a hornet-shaped (hrnet=curved) universe. That is if we look at two space dimensions because we obviously cannot see a curved three-dimensional space. This universe allegedly explains observations made on the universe. This is a finite universe. Here's a picture (note that the points of space where the ship turns back inward are problematic):

[image]

A spherical spacetime.
The most simple and most common form. This is the "balloon universe", due to the fact that the two-dimensional space part can be viewed as a balloon shape, which can be viewed to represent a curved form of a two-dimensional space.
This universe can be finite or infinite in spatial extent. And these spacetimes can have zero, negative or positive curvature.
Zero curvature corresponds to a spacetime that will continue to expand forever and this expansion will stop "after" infinite time, while its size is infinite. The balloon will stop expanding at infinity and have an infinite size.
The positive curvature represents a universe that expands and after a finite time, this expansion will stop. This universe obviously has a finite size. The balloon grows in size and will contract after some time (spacetime generally cannot stay motionless).
The negative curvature represents a spacetime that will expand at an ever-increasing rate. The ballon starts expanding and will grow in size faster and faster. It looks as if our own universe is (in these days) growing with this last feature.
In our universe, inflation has been assigned to a newly formed balloon spacetime. Initially, the universe expanded at an incredible rate and basically, the whole universe was formed during inflation. Since the end of inflation, the universe has only grown "only" three times as large as in the beginning. So what we see today is just a very tiny fraction of the whole. Behind the horizon the is a vast space.
The three universes are also referred to as flat, closed, or open:

[image]

The torus-shaped universe.
In 1984 this model was proposed as the [three-torus model]. [5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-torus_model_of_the_universe)This universe has a two-dimensional space equivalent of a torus. It has positive as well as negative curvature and can be finite or infinite (the infinite size will be reached after infinite time).

[image]

One can invent more shapes, of course, but they have to pass the tests of observation. I'm not aware that another form as the three mentioned is present though.

It is generally accepted (i.e., by most cosmologists) that our universe has a balloon=like topology. The amount of matter in these universes can be finite or infinite. In closed universes, the amount of matter will be finite while this amount is infinite in (asymptotically) flat or open universes.

What about time? Is spacetime eternal? That depends of course if there was something before the big bang (when the spacetimes started evolving very small size). For example, according to Smolin, there was a contracting universe present before the big bang (likewise he proposes that upon entering a black hole there will follow an exit to another spacetime, where there is a white hole present which ejects all that has fallen in from our own spacetime). It is generally claimed though that spacetime had a beginning in time and dependent on how much matter is in it and on the expansion speed, the universe will be there forever or not. It is thought (based on observations) that our universe is nearly flat and will expand forever.

So, what does the concept of an infinite universe mean? In the context of spacetimes that might be clear now: a universe is infinite if the spacetime has an infinite extent. Infinite space goes hand in hand with infinite time. The amount of matter contained in these universes can be finite or infinite.

Comment: The origin of the horn universe differs in the standard model. A finite distance back in time it is pinched down and cut off in a rounded end, known as the Big Bang. Time counts forward from zero at that beginning.

Comment: @GuyInchbald I don't see what you mean.

Comment: The tip of the horn does not extend infinitely into the past, as shown in the illustration. It has a blunt, more or less rounded end which is the inflationary period after the Big Bang, with the central point being the beginning of the Big bang and also the beginning of Time.

Comment: @GuyInchbald But (there I go again), doesn't the picture you are referring to represents space only? It resembles somewhat the picture of an expanding universe (a balloon one) in time though.

Comment: In the horn model, space is represented as a one-dimensional closed line, a circle. Time is the long axis. The surface as a whole represents spacetime.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Isn't this the balloon model? How do you go from one side to the other side as the spaceship in the picture does?

Comment: In the horn model, time runs to a maximum value and then turns round and runs backwards (whatever that might mean) - or in another variant, when Time reaches the end, the Universe explodes apart in a Big Rip. In the balloon model, space eventually stops expanding and starts shrinking, but time keeps moving forwards to a Big Crunch. It all depends on whether the global geometry of spacetime turns out to be positively or negatively curved, or flat. The torus is, at a global level, flat, the horn is negatively curved and the balloon is positively curved.

Comment: The torus does not need to have positive and negative *intrinsic* curvature. That's merely an artifact of trying to embed it in another space. See the comments under J. Murray's answer.

Comment: @user76284 This only goes to show how misleading a lower dimensional representation can be.

Comment: The idea that "spacetime had a beginning in time" is definitely not "generally accepted":  1/2 of the Nobel Prize award for 2020 went to Roger Penrose, whose "conformal cyclic cosmology" is eternal both to the past and to the future, with observational evidence of past aeons in several "anomalous spots of significantly higher temperature" that are visible in the CMB.  (I believe the main factor in the award was Penrose's contribution to the singularity theorems he formulated with Hawking in the 1960's, but 2010's CCC is compatible with them.)

Comment: @Edouard It's the first time I hear that he favors a cyclic model. Like always, he somehow contra-establishment. Which I like. I'm a fan of a cyclic universe myself. No beginning, no end. Maybe I return after the next big bang.

Comment: Yeah, emotionally it's great, and competes with other institutions which, as far as I've been able to tell, have generally done a pretty lousy and unmotivated job.  However, cyclic models are complicated physically:  You've probably heard that Tolman's model, formulated in the 1930's, ran into problems with an out-of-control increase in the density of entropy.  Pick up Penrose's pop-sci "Cycles of Time", which deals with the usual entropy-based time in a turgid, but nevertheless comprehensible, way.

Comment: @Edouard  Is it that difficult to deny the increase in entropy only at the turning points? To let the whole bang start in a new low-order state? After all, time is defined by increasing disorder and time did not "exist between" a big crunch and a big bang. So to speak.

Comment: Well, Penrose does ask for a lot (evaporating electrons, etc.), as you'll see if you want to look at the Wiki on CCC or a shorty version of the master's own work at https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10701-018-0162-3.pdf  .To tell you the truth, my own favorite among past- and future-eternal models is Nikodem Poplawski's, described in 2009-2021 papers you'll find by his name on Arxiv:  It's as easy to understand as reduction gears on a car, and suggests decreasing spatio-temporal scales rather than the increasing ones implied by Penrose.  But it uses Einstein-Cartan Theory, not GR.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask about an aspect of the universe as talked about by most cosmologists, you need to take into account the common general assumptions about the universe. One of the most common assumptions is that the universe is approximately the same everywhere taking an average of such things as average matter density or radiation density in a sufficiently large volume. The is called homogeneity. A second assumption is that the universe looks the same with respect to a sufficeient large scale in all directions. This is called isotropy.  With the assumption of homogeneity, an infinite universe is expected to have in a sufficiently large volume the same stuff and dynamics everywhere, just like a finite universe does. Different homogeneous universe models have different conditions at different times. It is a bit tricky do decide how to determine what it means for two different volumes in the universe to be at the same time. The simplest way to think about it is that if they have the same densities, then they are at the same time. Some of the other answers talk about rather strange shapes, like a hyper-torus. So far I have never been able to locate a description of **how** a torus can be homogeneous and isotropic.

Comment: A hyper-torus in this context is a cube, or other parallelepiped, with opposite faces identified. It has a continuous translation symmetry, but no continuous rotation symmetry, so it breaks isotropy but not homogeneity. Drawings of a torus as a donut shape are misleading since they suggest the surface is curved, which it isn't (as used in cosmology).

Comment: I understand benrg's description of a torus. It is not isotropic becasue it is possible to have a straight lines from a chosen origin that returns to itself with different angles relative the six parallel surfaces, AND such different paths will NOT be the same length. This violates isotropy.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make any sense to talk about spatial scale/distance without referring to some objects within space. Or have you ever used a ruler to measure the distance of two space points in empty space? This pretty much answers your question.